# bash - how to pass arg values to shell script within in a cronjob

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have cron entry that looks like this which works: (passing in 5 inputs)

```
30 10 * * 5 sh /home/test.sh hostnm101.abc /mypath/dir test foobar F008AR >> /logs/mytst.log 2>&1
```

I want to change it so I store inputs (4,5) `foobar` and `F008AR` in a separate file and read in by
script test.sh ($4,$5)

test.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# != 5 ]; then
    exit 1
fi

DIRDT=`date '+%Y%m%d'`
TSTDIR=$2/test/$DIRDATE
[ ! -d "$TSTDIR" ] && ( mkdir "$TSTDIR" || { echo 'mkdir command failed'; exit 1; } )

perl /home/dev/tstextr.pl -n $1 -b $2 -d $TSTDIR/ -s $3 -u $4 -p $5 -f $DIRDT
```

Is there any easy way to do this within the cron for those (2) input values? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright try this way.

1) Create a separate file `/mypath/dir/login.info` with content like this (username/password in separate lines):

```
foobar
F008AR
```

2) Modify your test.sh like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $# != 4 ]; then
    exit 1
fi

DIRDT=`date '+%Y%m%d'`
TSTDIR=$2/test/$DIRDATE
[ ! -d "$TSTDIR" ] && ( mkdir "$TSTDIR" || { echo 'mkdir command failed'; exit 1; } )

IFS="
"
arr=( $(<$2/$4) )
#echo "username=${arr[0]}   password=${arr[1]}"

perl /home/dev/tstextr.pl -n $1 -b $2 -d $TSTDIR/ -s $3 -u ${arr[0]} -p ${arr[1]} -f $DIRDT
```

3) Have your cron command like this:

```
30 10 * * 5 sh /home/test.sh hostnm101.abc /mypath/dir test login.info >> /logs/mytst.log 2>&1
```

#### Summary

- IFS stands for Internal Field Separator (IFS) in bash

I am using it like this:

```
IFS="
"
```

Which means make new line character as field separator (since we are storing username and password in 2 separate lines). And then this line to read file `/mypath/dir/login.info` into an array:

```
arr=( $(<$2/$4) )
```

- First line (username) is read into `$arr[0]`
- Second line (password) is read into `$arr[1]`

You can echo it to check read content:

```
echo "username=${arr[0]}"
echo "password=${arr[1]}"
```

Comment: this is cool! thanks a lot. Can you tell me the basics of that code starting with `IFS` and what it is doing? thank you.

Comment: Added some explanation in summary section above. Glad that it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

cron executes with sh -c so:

```
sh /home/test.sh hostnm101.abc /mypath/dir test `cat /mypath/dir/foobar_file` `cat /mypath/dir/F008AR_file` >> /logs/mytst.log 2>&
```